# LinkedList's indexOf() vs lastIndexOf() methods optimization

Tags: java, linked-list

Really want to know why linked list indexof() does not take advantage of the fact that "header" entry has a null element for increased performance when it is passed a null "target" :

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    int index = 0;
    if (o==null) {
        // header.element guaranteed null, no chance of looping past header
        for (Entry e = header.next; e.element != null; e = e.next) {
            index++;
        }
        // if index < size, null was found, else we looped to header
        return (index < size) ? index: -1;
    } else {
        for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
            if (o.equals(e.element))
                return index;
            index++;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If we apply a similar transformation to lastIndexOf() it yields very pretty results:

```
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
    int index = size - 1;
    if (o==null) {
        for (Entry e = header.previous; e.element != null;
             e = e.previous, index--);
    } else {
        for (Entry e = header.previous; e != header && !o.equals(e.element);
             e = e.previous, index--);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Is it intentional ?

Comment: Where does this code come from? According to the comment, the header of this list has always a null element. So which optimization would you like to introduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what JRE are you referring to, but apart of syntactic sugar the only relevant difference I see is this:

```
// if index < size, null was found, else we looped to header
return (index < size) ? index: -1;
```

The reason for this is, for `lastIndexOf()` we start at last element and upon miss, we end up at header with index `-1`. But for `indexOf()`, we start at 0-th element and upon miss we end up at header with `index == size` - however, we want to return `-1` upon miss, so we have to add the extra condition.